# utility method for safe dereference in Java

Tags: java

Groovy allows me to say

```
x?.getY()
```

instead of the verbose

```
x == null ? null : x.getY().
```

Java does not allow custom operators, but I can imagine a utility method that's used like so:

```
safe(x).getY();
```

Is there any standard library in the world's Maven repos that does this kind of thing? If no, and I wanted to include it in an open source library (like apache.commons.lang), where would it best fit?

Edit: sample implementation of `safe()`:

```
public static <T> T safe(T x) {
    if (x==null) {
        return new NullReturningMock<T>();
    } else {
        return x;
    }
}
```

Comment: Ewwwwww.  That'd inevitably require (slow) reflection.  Do it the old-fashioned way, please.

Comment: @LouisWasserman Not necessarily, you could also proxy concrete classes using something like CGLIB. (Overkill, with lots of bug-prone code, but faster!)

Answer (score 2):

Not exactly what you were asking for but as a Java programmer that spent some time coding in [Scala](http://www.scala.org/) I can recommend [Google Guava's](https://guava.dev) implementation of [Optional](https://guava.dev/releases/snapshot-jre/api/docs/com/google/common/base/Optional.html).
[Elvis and Safe Operator Proposal](http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/coin-dev/2009-March/000047.html) didn't make it to Java 7, maybe for 8.
[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/271526/how-to-avoid-null-statements-in-java) may be an interesting read.

**Update 2023**: Still no Elvis Operator in Java, but [`Optional`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Optional.html) has been part of the Standard Library since Java 8.